# How to add authentication to Event Notification?

Tags: authentication, notifications, http-headers, box-api

I looked through documentation on Event Notification (http://developers.box.com/webhooks/).

I would like to call an REST API, with basic authentication. Is there a way to do this?

like, customizing the HTTP headers (like adding Authorization:Basic ...) of the HTTP call triggered?

Answer (score 0):

There currently isn't support for passing in special headers. You can, however, use HTTP Basic Auth by specifying it in the URL for event notifications to be sent to e.g.

```
https://username:password@www.example.com/path
```

Comment: That is helpful. Is there a way to generate this dynamically?
Meaning, e.g. I want to change the http string based on "logged in user".